# Tensorflow-serving: Serving a hashmap

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

it looks like there is a hashmap_source_adapter.cc that can be used for serving hashmap. We are trying to figure out if we can use it directly or if some special wiring is needed. It seems that https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/46915c6de3f993d4385aaa1dd2cefcce9fbc658a/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc#L271 CreateTensorflowPlatformConfigMap does not allow for hashmap to be served. Is there any sample code or sample configuration that will let us use hashmap_source_adapter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

hashmap_source_adapter is merely a toy example of how to build a custom type of servable. It is not meant to be used for any "real" serving :)

-Chris (TF-Serving team)